# SignalR works slow in UWP and fast in console application

Tags: c#, uwp, signalr

I have a SignalR server which sends certain messages to all the clients connected to it. I have created two sample clients one in UWP and another one is a simple console application in C#. I simply log a message once the client's method is called from SignalR.

Dramatically, the console application logs the data as soon as the server sends, but the UWP application adds a delay of about 6-30 seconds in it. Although it triggers frequently sometimes, it is able to reproduce the issue 6 out of 10 times.

Below is the code for the UWP client, similarly, I have logged message in console application.

```
async Task SetupSignalR()
    {

        var conn = new HubConnection(baseUrl);
        Writer.Text += (string.Format("Creating hub proxy with :{0}\n", baseUrl));
        var proxy = conn.CreateHubProxy("PumpStatusHub");


        Writer.Text += "Starting Connection\n";


        try
        {
            conn.Start().Wait();
            Writer.Text += "Connection started\n";
            proxy.Invoke("OpenPortReading").Wait();//, UserName, TextBoxMessage.Text);
            Writer.Text += "Port invoked\n";
            proxy.On<string>("ReadUdpData", OnMessage);
        }
        catch (HttpRequestException ex)
        {
            Writer.Text += "Unable to connect to server: Start server 
                            before connecting clients.\n";
            Writer.Text += ex.Message + "\n";
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Writer.Text += ex.Message + "\n";
            Task.Delay(3000).Wait();
            SetupSignalR().Wait();
        }
    }

    private void OnMessage(string obj)
    {
        Windows.ApplicationModel.Core.CoreApplication.MainView.
            Dispatcher.RunAsync(CoreDispatcherPriority.High, (DispatchedHandler)(() =>
            {
                Writer.Text += string.Format("Message received: {0}\n"
                                            , counter++);
            }));
    }
```

Any help would be highly appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please provide code, otherwise the question will be closed.

Comment: What's your testing environment for UWP app, could you please change a device or update the network connection for testing again and check if it has the same result?  What's the bad influence for you if  the data receive slow?  And what't the data you are sending from the sever?

Comment: On the same testing environment the console application client shows data right away, but uwp client shows delay

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got this fixed by collaborating with SignalR developers and found an interesting thing that on using Server sent events as transport there was an issue with SignalR for UWP client which they are fixing.

I resolved the issue by using Long polling transport as Windows 7 does not support WebSockets.